# case when subquery multiple row

Tags: db2, subquery, multiple-records

I have tree table on DB2 9.7.01

**Table A** (here are start data)

```
codeA |type
-----------------------------
P003 |P
K001 |K
```

**Table B** (here are product data)

```
codeB |description
-----------------------------
P001 |Product one
P002 |Product two
P003 |Product three
```

**Table C** (here are kit data; kit include one or more product)

```
codeC |description |codeB
-----------------------------
K001 |Kit one      |P001
K001 |Kit one      |P002
```

i need to read every record of A table and if field type is "K" then query must return its multiple product; if type is "P" then query  return only one product;
this is the query to accomplish

```
Select a.codeA AS codeExternal, 
case 
when a.type = 'K' then (select C.CODEB from C  where A.CODEA = C.CODEC)
 else a.CODEA
end as codeInternal
from 
A 
left B
ON a.CODEA = B.CODEB
```

but the query return only

```
codeExt | code Int
---------------------------
P003    | P003
K001    | P001
```

and not the awaited

```
codeExt | code Int
---------------------------
P003    | P003
K001    | P001
K001    | P002
```

Comment: Surely you want to join `Table C` as well, since it's only that table that has the kit composition information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Something like this:

```
select A.CodeA CodeExt, B.CodeB CodeInt
from A inner join B on A.CodeA=B.CodeB and A.type='P'
union all
select A.CodeA CodeExt, C.CodeB CodeInt
from A inner join C on A.CodeA=C.CodeC and A.type='K'
```

if you want remove doublon, use union and not union all

Comment: thankU very much but second select will be
select A.CodeA CodeExt, C.CodeB CodeInt
from A right join C on A.CodeA=C.CodeC and A.type='K'